# Draw formatted text with libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

How can I draw formatted text with libgdx's Scene2D?

There is what I found: [libgdx/Color Markup Language](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language)
But it's not enough. I want to implement some kind of markdown via `MarkdownLabelActor`.

So, I must create `Bitmaps` for each type of expected text(*italic*/**bold**/sized) and render them in right place according to formatting tags.
Is it everything okay with my plan? :)

It's strange that there are no any markdown/html formatting implementations on github. Or I just don't notice something?